# How was this question closed?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I was looking at some of the review votes I has cast. (I like to see how well my votes agree with other SO reviewers.)

What I didn't understand was how [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3600917) was closed.

[image]

I voted to keep it open. One other reviewer voted the same; the other disagreed.

Given these results, I expected the question to still be open. What am I missing?

Comment: Close votes directly on the question and not the review queue? A [link to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631648/implement-pointer-virtual-pure-functions) would have been helpful - and it shows the 5 closers, the last one matches the one in the review queue.

Comment: @Oded, link added. Do I understand that votes outside of the review queue do not show up in the review tab? If so, could you add that as an answer?

Comment: That's right - they did not come in as part of a review, so will not show up there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close votes that did not come in via the review queue will not show up on the review item.

In this case, there were 4 pending close votes on the question - a single person to agree with the closure via the queue was enough to close the question.

This can be seen directly on the question page (as well on the review item page directly), in the notification area just after the question - it lists the closers.